# Issue in uploading image file on server using postman in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, intervention

I am using intervention for file resize functionality and for file uploading.
In controller I am just checking `hasFile()` or not. so, everytime I got "no" in response even if I am sending it properly using postman. what can be the issue ?

**my route**

```
Route::post('contact/image/upload',[  
  'as'=> 'intervention.postresizeimage',
  'uses'=>'contactController@upload_image'
]);
```

**code in controller**

```
public function upload_image(Request $request){

      if((preg_match("/^[789]\d{9}$/", $request->header('UID')))){
        if($request->hasFile('photo'))
          return "yes";
        else
          return "no";


        $photo = $request->file('photo');
        $imagename = time().'.'.$photo->getClientOriginalExtension(); 

        $destinationPath_thumb = storage_path('images/thumbnail_images');
        $thumb_img = Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->resize(100, 100);
        $thumb_img->save($destinationPath_thumb.'/'.$imagename,80);

        $destinationPath_medium = storage_path('images/medium_images');
        $medium_img = Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->resize(500, 500);
        $medium_img->save($destinationPath_medium.'/'.$imagename,80);

        $destinationPath_original = storage_path('images/original_images');
        $photo->move($destinationPath_original, $imagename);

        $user = \App\User::select(['inst_id'])->where('mobile','=',$request->header('UID'))->first();

        $update_img = \App\Contact::where([['id','=',$request->ID],['inst_id','=',$user->inst_id]])->update(['image'=>$imagename]);

        if($update_img)
          $response = response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>0,  'error_msg'=>'', 'message'=>'Profile updated']);
        else
          $response = response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>1,  'error_msg'=>'some went wrong', 'message'=>'Please try again']);
      }
      else
         $response = response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>1,  'error_msg'=>'wrong mobile in UID header','message'=>'wrong mobile no. in header']);

    return  $response;

  }
```

Comment: Do `dd($request->all())` and see what it shows. Most probably, `photo` is not the correct name of the posted data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also think so **photo** is not correct name for the posted data.
You may see the given images of Postman:

[Postman Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3kkQ.png)

[Postman Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFT7K.png)

Comment: I got it . Thanks a ton MdRasel Ahmed.

Answer (score 1):

What's your enctype attribute in the form tag? It should look like this if you upload files:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```